# What does it mean to find the irreducible representations of a given group?

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, representation-theory

Given a vector space $V$ and a group $G$, I am well aware of the definitions of everything noted in my title. A representation of $G$ on $V$ is a homomorphism $T: G \to GL(V)$. An irreducible representation is a representation with no $G$-invariant subspace other than the trivial ones, $\{0\}$ and $V$. But all of this presupposes that I know $V$. How do different choices of $V$ affect things? For example, I read on Wikipedia that the trivial representation, $\forall g, T(g) = I $, is irreducible. How is this the case? If $V$ is any $n$-dimensional space then there are clearly $n$ different 1-dimensional $G$-invariant subspaces (pick $n$ linearly independent vectors in $V$)? There is obviously a lot I am missing here.

My ultimate goal is to find all the irreducible representations of the permutation group $S_3$, but I'm not sure I understand how to go about this until I understand how to fix $V$ or, perhaps, whether $V$ doesn't matter?

Comment: Regarding trivial representations, you're right that n-dimensional space contains many 1-dimensional invariant subspaces (though way more than just n!) so it shouldn't in general be irreducible, but how about if V is 1-dimensional?

Comment: For each vector space $V$, there may or may not be an irreducible representation of $G$ acting on $V$.  And of course if $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic vector spaces then one of them carries an irreducible representation if and only if the other does.

Comment: @JBL Does that mean I need to consider the entire space (category) of sets? I know the dimensional theorem will give an upper bound on these irreps

Comment: … in general if any $V$ is permitted. For $S_3$ I can probably guess the “right” $V$, but in general?

Comment: @KyleMiller Absolutey. But what do I do as a general algorithm for other irreps? Which $V$ do I check? I have to imagine there’s some well-known theorem I’m missing.

Comment: The number of irreducible representations equals the number of conjugacy classes, which is three. The squares of the degrees add up to the order of the group, so we're looking for three positive integers whose squares add up to six. The only solution is two of degree one, and one of degree two. So now you know the dimensions of the various spaces $V$.

Comment: That seems to be a strategy which would be intractable for large groups. Is that the most general way to go about it? @GerryMyerson

Comment: In general it is a difficult problem to compute the irreducible representation. Especially when you are working over fields of characteristic $p$ and $p$ divides $|G|$, then there is no efficient algorithm. For instance, the degrees of the irreducible representations of $S_{20}$ in characteristic 2 are not known.

Comment: What @Brauer says. There are lots of other theorems that can be applied. I used to give it as an end-of-semester project in a Group Theory course to find the character table of a group of order $16$ from its generators and relations. Students found it challenging, but many were successful. So it can be done, for smallish groups over the complex numbers at least, but it's several orders of magnitude harder than, say, solving quadratic equations.

Comment: There are general methods for finite groups, but they require probably more theory than you know at this point, and they can be exceedingly hard to do by hand. A "textbook" problem, such as finding the representations of $S_3$ is most likely solved by some ad hoc attempts and then using a suitable theorem that says that you must have found all up to equivalence.

Comment: @ahulpke Thank you for your clarification and to everyone else above for their comments. This all clears everything up perfectly for me.

Comment: Since you used the word "category": for every group $G$ there's a category $\operatorname{Rep}(G)$ of the finite-dimensional representations of $G$, where morphisms are $G$-intertwining homomorphisms. The problem of "finding the irreducible representations" is "finding a representative for each isomorphism class of irreducible representation in $\operatorname{Rep}(G)$." If $G$ is finite and, say, the characteristic of the field is zero, then this category is, up to an equivalence of categories, determined by just the cardinality of the set of isomorphism classes (!).

Comment: Regarding algorithms, for certain classes of groups it's possible to fully describe the irreducible representations. There's a really nice theory for symmetric groups, where irreducibles are indexed by Young diagrams. Schur-Weyl duality is a way to take these and give the irreducible finite-dimensional representations of the general linear group.

Comment: @KyleMiller That is unfortunately largely over my head but I nevertheless appreciate you pointing out “what is ahead”. The summit truly never lies in sight and that’s a great thing. Thanks again!